# Converting associative POST data input into a serialized array

Tags: php, serialization

I'm using a multidimensional array in a form and I want to parse these values into a serialized array to be stored in my database.  Here's the relevant section of my HTML form:

```
<select name="week_days[monday]"><option value=""></option><option value="preferred">Preferred</option><option value="restricted">Restricted</option></select>
<select name="week_days[tuesday]"><option value=""></option><option value="preferred">Preferred</option><option value="restricted">Restricted</option></select>
<select name="week_days[wednesday]"><option value=""></option><option value="preferred">Preferred</option><option value="restricted">Restricted</option></select>
<select name="week_days[thursday]"><option value=""></option><option value="preferred">Preferred</option><option value="restricted">Restricted</option></select>
```

I want to then create an array in my model called week_days.  An example of what I want the array to look like is this:

`array('monday'=>'preferred','tuesday'=>'','wednesday'=>'restricted','thursday'=>'');`

I will then serialize() this array for storage in my database.  How do I go about converting the multidimensional array input into an array for serialization?

Comment: This is not a multi-dimensional array.. It is simply an associative array..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you submit this in a form,  you will get a `$_POST['week_days']` which will be equal to your array in your question

Comment: Well that was incredibly easy... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some example code to demonstrate:

```
<pre><?php

if ($_POST['week_days']) {
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r(serialize($_POST['week_days']));
}

?></pre>
<form method="post">
<select name="week_days[monday]"><option value=""></option><option value="preferred">Preferred</option><option value="restricted">Restricted</option></select>
<select name="week_days[tuesday]"><option value=""></option><option value="preferred">Preferred</option><option value="restricted">Restricted</option></select>
<select name="week_days[wednesday]"><option value=""></option><option value="preferred">Preferred</option><option value="restricted">Restricted</option></select>
<select name="week_days[thursday]"><option value=""></option><option value="preferred">Preferred</option><option value="restricted">Restricted</option></select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Which outputs (based on what's selected):

```
Array
(
    [week_days] => Array
        (
            [monday] => preferred
            [tuesday] => restricted
            [wednesday] => restricted
            [thursday] => preferred
        )

)
a:4:{s:6:"monday";s:9:"preferred";s:7:"tuesday";s:10:"restricted";s:9:"wednesday";s:10:"restricted";s:8:"thursday";s:9:"preferred";}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well... Quite straightforward really if I've understood you correctly:

```
$serialized = serialize ( $_POST['week_days'] );
```

will do what you want...

That said, a couple of notes:

- You might want to make a new table where you store the days and have a boolean column for preferred or not
- This is not a multi-dimensional array, but an associative array =)